# Python 3.x - using text string as variable name

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to avoid to multiply functions in code by using

```
def Return_Label(self,number)
```

with a parameter.

Any Idea how to use string in order to define variable name usable to `.set` value to `StringVar()`?

## Example code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class WINDOW():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Settings_Window()

    def Settings_Window(self):
        self.settings_window = tk.Tk()
        self.settings_window.minsize(200,200)
        self.entry = Entry(self.settings_window)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry2 = Entry(self.settings_window)
        self.entry2.pack()
        self.label1input = StringVar()
        self.label = Label(self.settings_window,textvariable=self.label1input, bg='yellow')
        self.label.pack(expand='yes',fill='x')
        self.label2input = StringVar()
        self.label2 = Label(self.settings_window, textvariable=self.label2input, bg='yellow')
        self.label2.pack(expand='yes', fill='x')
        self.button = Button(self.settings_window,text='SETUP1',command=self.Next)
        self.button.pack()
        self.button2 = Button(self.settings_window,text='SETUP2',command=self.Next2)
        self.button2.pack()
        self.settings_window.mainloop()

    def Next(self):
        self.number=1
        self.Return_Label(self.number)

    def Next2(self):
        self.number=2
        self.Return_Label(self.number)

    def Return_Label(self,number):
        self.entry_field_value = self.entry.get()
        print(self.entry_field_value)
        #self.label1input.set(self.entry_field_value)
        setattr(self,'label'+str(number)+'input.set',self.entry_field_value)

window=WINDOW()
```

Comment: Do you mean `getattr(self, 'label'+str(number)+'input').set(self.entry_field_value)`?

Comment: Lists and dicts are your friend.

Comment: getattr… works. Thanks. Although fully agree that code should be shorter / neater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer a list approach to managing multiple entry fields and updating values.
By using list you can use the index value to manage the labels as well :D.

See the below example of how you can use list to deal with all the values and updates.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.minsize(200, 200)
        self.entry_list = []
        self.label_list = []
        entry_count = 2

        for i in range(entry_count):
            self.entry_list.append(Entry(self))
            self.entry_list[i].pack()

        for i in range(entry_count):
            self.label_list.append(Label(self,bg='yellow'))
            self.label_list[i].pack(expand='yes', fill='x')

        Button(self, text='SETUP', command=self.Return_Label).pack()

    def Return_Label(self):
        for ndex, lbl in enumerate(self.label_list):
            lbl.config(text=self.entry_list[ndex].get())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create *lists* of objects rather than individual attributes for each object. For example,

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.settings_window()

    def Settings_Window(self):
        self.settings_window = tk.Tk()
        self.settings_window.minsize(200,200)

        self.entries = [
            Entry(self.settings_window), 
            Entry(self.settings_window)
        ]

        for e in self.entries:
            e.pack()

        self.labelinputs = [
            StringVar(),
            StringVar()
        ]

        self.labels = [
            Label(self.settings_window, textvariable=label, bg='yellow')
            for label in self.labelinputs
        ]

        for l in self.labels:
            l.pack(expand='yes', fill='x')

        self.buttons = [
            Button(self.settings_window,text='SETUP1',command=lambda: self.return_label(0))
            Button(self.settings_window,text='SETUP2',command=lambda: self.return_label(1))
        ]

        for b in self.buttons:
            b.pack()

        self.settings_window.mainloop()

    def return_label(self,number):
        entry_field_value = self.entry.get()
        self.labelsinput[number].set(entry_field_value)

window=WINDOW()
```

Comment: True. This was a quick & dirty example aimed at getting my point at variable usage. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamicly computing variable names should be avoided at all costs. They are difficult to do correctly, and it makes your code hard to understand, hard to maintain, and hard to debug.

Instead, store the widgets in a dictionary or list. For example:

```
def __init___(self):
    ...
    self.vars = {}
    ...
    self.vars[1] = StringVar()
    self.vars[2] = StringVar()
    ...

def Return_Label(self,number):
    self.entry_field_value = self.entry.get()
    var = self.vars[number]
    var.set(self.entry_field_value)
```

Though, you really don't need to use `StringVar` at all -- they usually just add extra overhead without providing any extra value. You can save the labels instead of the variables, and call `configure` on the labels

```
self.labels[1] = Label(...)
...
self.labels[number].configure(text=self.entry_field_value)
```